# Python prints None despite not being inside function

Tags: python

So I'm still relatively new to Python programming and so at the moment I'm just trying to create a simple password program. If the use has opened the program before, then it will skip the create a password bit. I have done this by creating a file which will contain the number of times the file has been opened. If the number is less than 1 then it will ask for the new password.

This bit works fine, I just have the problem that when running the following code, "None" is printed. I understand the whole function return bit but the code I'm using isn't in a function so I'm not sure why it is happening. Would really appreciate help in fixing this!

```
fo = open("openNo.txt", "r")
openNo = fo.read()

if int(openNo)<1:
    pw = input(print("Please enter a password: ")) #creating a new password
    pwCheck = pw
else:
    pwCheck = input(print("Please enter your password: ")) #using an existing password

fo.close()

if pwCheck == "password":
    print("Welcome!")
else:
    print("access denied")
```

Comment: `input` prints the argument passed to it as a prompt; in this case, `None`, the return value from `print`. Just do e.g. `input("Please enter a password: ")`. Also note: https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah thanks a lot. Also that's useful to know there is an automatic password module. Though this was more of an exercise using a combination of different things but I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @TobyKing I think you're misunderstanding, the `input` function is defined as `input(prompt=None, /)`-- basically meaning that whenever you call `input` with a parameter, it'll implicitly print that parameter. If you want modules to actually handle passwords I would use `getpass`

Comment: @клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас Thanks for the answer, but once again this is just a short exercise, I'm not actually dealing with passwords, it was potentially a bad example however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing that, in fact: you are passing the result of `print` to `input`. There's no need to do that.

```
pw = input("Please enter a password: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Please enter a password: ") returns none so you are seeing none when you run the code
```